# Using OAuth2 with username and password

Tags: python, ruby, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have gained REST API acess to a certain service as part of a beta. I was told the authorization is throught OAuth2.

I got the following:

1. ID
2. SECRET
3. SITE

I also got a code sample in Ruby:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(key, secret, :site => site) 
token = client.password.get_token('your_email@mail.com', 'your_password') 
access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, token) 
JSON.parse access_token.get("/v1/users/me").body rescue {}
```

I'm trying to implement this same snippet in python with the `oauth2` package, without success:

```
consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=self._client_id,
                           secret=self._client_secret)
request_token_url = "api.theservice.com/"
token = oauth2.Token(key=self._email, secret=self._password)
client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
pprint.pprint(resp)
pprint.pprint(content)
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url + 'v1/users/me', "GET")
pprint.pprint(resp)
pprint.pprint(content)
```

The second response contains the following:

```
'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="Doorkeeper", error="invalid_token", '
                    'error_description="The access token is invalid"',
```

I also tried creating a `oauth2.Client` object without a token, and checked the first response for an `access_token`, but nothing of the sort came through.

What is the proper way to authenticate here?

Comment: Is this service using a three-legged OAuth like Twitter described [here](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2/wiki/Twitter-Three-legged-OAuth)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see neither oauth2 nor requests-oauth2 support username/password strategy. So you need to obtain access token by yourself.

Check your API docs for details, but in general it should be something like that:

```
r = requests.post('http://api.theservice.com/auth',
                  data = {'email':email, 'password': password}).json()

token = oauth2.Token(key=r['key'], secret=r['secret'])
consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=self._client_id,
                           secret=self._client_secret)

client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
```